# Drupal 7 Fields Not Showing Up

Tags: entities, users, organic-groups

I have a Drupal 7 install that acts as a user network site. Users have 'member' permissions but are not administrators.

Some user fields are hidden via the field permissions module, but the rest should be viewable and editable by the user.

After updating the OG module, as well as the Webforms module, all custom fields added to the user node disappeared, both for registered members and new applicants (http://member.clevergirlscollective.com/drupal/?q=user/register , there should be several additional fields here).

I've adjusted permissions both at the field level and at the user node level, but for some reason this still happens.

Any ideas you have would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues that could be plaguing you related to various configurations. However as a starting point, let's start with the basics:

1. Clear all caches. This will clear most issues caused by upgrades.
2. Rebuild permissions. Sometimes new access permissions or changes to old ones occur during upgrades. Since the fields still exist, but are not seen in the content view, it's possible that a permissions error is in your way.

   http://www.example.com/admin/reports/status/rebuild
3. Check your PHP logs. Sometimes issues can occur with PHP where upgrades adding new features break things in a subtle way. Running out of memory, or breaching the 'max_input_vars' threshold are common issues I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "After updating the OG module", from which version to which version? Did you update to a development version? If so, was this absolutely necessary?

My experiences with the latest OG dev versions are that there are a lot of things they break in my install and things still need to be fixed. Also, the "Organic groups access control" greatly affects content permissions and I've noticed some funky things going on with that module alone even on the production module.

Comment: I upgraded to the 2.x-dev version. Probably a bad idea, although it has several features I needed. I manaaged to get permissions for users who are logged in, but am still struggling to get non-logged-in users to see custom fields in the registration form...

Answer (score 0):

You didn't explicitly mention that you did this, so I'll throw this out there:  did you clear your cache?  I always do that after updating modules as sometimes funky behavior can occur if you do not.